# UK visitor visa for a Pakistani tourist rejected after previously studying there, how to help this situation?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, study, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani national residing in UAE. Have been working here in Dubai for the past 4 years in a secure job. I studied in the UK previously for my undergrad and consequently pursued a professional ACCA qualification there but left halfway as I was not interested in Finance. At no point did I ever overstay and always had a valid visa.

**Previous Rejections:** US visit visa was rejected due to no strong ties as well as my Canada student visa when I had intended to go for masters last year - of course I disclosed all this in my visitor visa application to the UK recently.

I wanted to plan a trip to London as I hadn't visited the UK since I last left and wanted to go back I guess for nostalgia. I studied in Manchester however chose to book my tickets to London first and then travel by train to Manchester and see friends. In my visa application I wrote tourism as my purpose of travel, had fully paid flight tickets, letter from my employer stating my salary, position and that I need to return by a certain date, also had hotel bookings and bank statements from Dubai and Pakistan. I was very transparent.

My visa was rejected under financial verification and also strong ties. Now this strong ties reason has been a common theme in all my visit visa applications. How do I as a single man in my 20s prove ties to UAE? I have a job, details of which I have provided. What mistakes am I making? What could help?

Comment: Please upload your refusal letter, blacking out personal details

Comment: _"My visa was rejected under financial verification (ok this I can work with)"_ . In most cases your finances are not something you can correct in short term. Please see [this excellent answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/50234) for a detailed explanation of what a visa officer sees in your finances. Without a refusal notice and given your history of prior refusals, the general advice is that you should build a good travel history to other countries first.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a single Pakistani male in his 20s working a regular job in the UAE will find it extremely difficult to prove his strong ties to the UAE. The visa officers believe that you have nothing to come back to. You will have to wait until you are more settled with a family.

Comment: The multiple previous rejections won't help matters.